# How do I upload an SSH key to Visual Studio Team Services (for Git repos)

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm excited that VSTS is supporting Git with SSH authentication. Unfortunately I cannot figure out where within the Visual Studio Team Services website to upload my SSH key.

The articles linked to below makes it sound easy, but I'm struggling.  Can someone direct me by chance?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb187345%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/11/git-experience-futures-january-2016/

Comment: Quick update: I have successfully connected to VSTS using SSH. I did not catch exactly when support was implemented, but it has been live for at least a few weeks now.

Answer (score 4):

The Git support for VSTS is yet to rolled out for all the accounts. Once it is rolled out.

You can manage your ssh keys by clicking on `Clone` in the `Code` tab and then `Manage Your SSH keys`

[image]

Comment: Once SSH support was rolled out to all, this is the solution that worked for me. And the link to @RaviTezu's answer closely matches the steps I took. Thanks for the help. SSH support is great.

Answer (score 2):

SSH support for Git repos in Visual Studio Team Services is currently in private preview being tested.  If the experience works out well, then it will be deployed to all customer accounts.  Here is the current documentation for the SSH experience:  [Use SSH Keys to Authenticate with Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/get-started/code/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate)

[image: Using SSH while Cloning Git Repo with Visual Studio Team Services]

Answer (score 1):

Here's the latest post on Git for VSTS: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/04/14/git-experience-futures-april-2016/

The SSH support for Git is yet to be released.

Hope this helps.